# Ternary Operator C++ Ostream to String incompatible operands

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator, nested, ostream

```
return (dayCheck = false) ? cout << "On the " << day << 
"th Day of Christmas, My True Love Gave to Me: " 
<< endl << Christmas(day, count, true) : 
          (count != 0) ? cout << arr[count] << endl 
          << Christmas(day, count - 1, true) : 
                  Christmas(day + 1, day + 1, false);
```

I'm trying to do a nested ternary operator but I can't figure out a way to make the operands compatible in the nested operator one is an ostream and the other is a string (char). Is there a way to cast this or is there another way I need to format it to keep it nested? (For this particular code I'm actually focusing on the nesting of the ternary operator)

Comment: You probably meant `dayCheck == false` (which I think is better written as `!dayCheck`, unless you follow the style recommendation which says "use enums instead of booleans to indicate which alternative to use"). That's a side issue to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `cout`.

Also, it makes the code more readable when you add paranthesis at suitable locations.

Use:

```
return (dayCheck = false) ?

    // Add a pair of paranthesis for the first statement.
    (cout << "On the " << day << "th Day of Christmas, My True Love Gave to Me: " << endl << Christmas(day, count, true)) : 
    (count != 0) ?

    // Add a pair of paranthesis for the next first statement.
    (cout << arr[count] << endl << Christmas(day, count - 1, true)) : 

    // Add a pair of paranthesis for the last statement.
    (cout << Christmas(day + 1, day + 1, false));
  // ^^^^ The missing cout
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second ternary expression. The two cases do not have the same return type.
The first returns an `ostream` object

```
cout << arr[count] << endl << Christmas(day, count - 1, true)
```

and the second returns whatever `Christmas` returns

```
Christmas(day + 1, day + 1, false)
```

To fix this, make the second case also return an ostream object:

```
return (dayCheck = false) ? cout << "On the " << day << 
"th Day of Christmas, My True Love Gave to Me: " 
<< endl << Christmas(day, count, true) : 
          (count != 0) ? cout << arr[count] << endl 
          << Christmas(day, count - 1, true) : 
                  cout << Christmas(day + 1, day + 1, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (dayCheck == false) ?
        (cout << "On the " << day << "th Day of Christmas, My True Love Gave to Me: " << endl << Christmas(day, count, true)) :

        (count != 0) ? cout << arr[count] << endl << Christmas(day, count - 1, true) :

        (cout << Christmas(day + 1, day + 1, false));
```

So that seemed to fix the issue and Christmas is returning an int but now it's showing a no viable conversion from ostream to string. The error now appears throughout the code section starting at the (dayCheck == false).

```
(dayCheck == false)
```

Comment: What is the return type of this function we're in? If it's a string, then yep, this won't work. You would want to use `std::stringstream` instead of `std::cout`, and return `stringstream.string()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two related problems here. First, both branches of the ternary operator need to have the same type (which is the type of the result of the operator), so if `Christmas` returns a `string`, you can't have another branch of the ternary operator which returns an `ostream&`.

The second problem is precisely that `Christmas` allegedly returns a `string`. (I assume that the return statement is actually inside the `Christmas` function.) The intent of the function is not to return a `string`, but rather to a string and, recursively, other strings to `cout`. So the only meaningful return types are `ostream&` or `void`. But if you make a change like that, you'll find that `cout << Christmas(...)` is an error, because you can't send (`<<`) a stream to itself.

It's interesting to see how to solve this problem with an `ostream&` return, although it will end up looking quite different from your current program. The following is essentially flawed, because a function like `Christmas` should be able to output to any stream, but we can fix that later. Let's start by just assuming that the function returns an `ostream&` and that it also outputs to that same `ostream`. Since the function returns the `ostream&`, we should use that instead of `cout`, so we might have something roughly like this:

```
std::ostream& Christmas(int day, int count, bool startStanza) {
  return (/* We're not finished */)
            ? Christmas(/* the next line */) << /* This line */;
            : std::cout;  /* FIXME */
}
```

However, the recursion has now been turned on its head. The recursed call happens *before*  we manage to send the current line into the `ostream` returned. So we actually need to start at the end, and recurse towards the beginning. As it turns out, that's not difficult, and we can even get rid of the boolean:

```
std::ostream& Christmas(int day, int count) {
  return day ? count <= day ? Christmas(day, count + 1) << gift[count] << '\n'
                            : Christmas(day - 1, 1) << "On the "
                                                    << day
                                                    << " day of Christmas, "
                                                       "my true love gave to me:\n"
             : std::cout; /* FIXME */
}
```

If we're going to use `<<`, we might as well be consistent. Suppose we wanted to start the whole thing off by writing:

```
std::cout << Christmas;
```

To do this, we need two things:

1. A class object, to hold the `ostream&`, which has a member function similar to the above.
2. An [I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), which is a function, to construct the object, and invoke its member function to output the carol.

Here's how it all looks:

```
class Singer {
    friend std::ostream& Christmas(std::ostream& out);
    Singer(std::ostream& out) : out(out) {}
    std::ostream& sing(int day, int count) {
      return day ? count <= day ? sing(day, count + 1) << (count == 1 && day > 1 ? "and " : "")
                                                       << gift[count - 1] << '\n'
                                : sing(day - 1, 1) << "\nOn the "
                                                   << day
                                                   << "th day of Christmas, "
                                                      "my true love gave to me:\n"
                 : out;
    }
  private:
    std::ostream& out;
    static const char *gift[12];
};

std::ostream& Christmas(std::ostream& out) { return Singer(out).sing(12,1); }
```

See it live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f801eadf8f5261e